# How to disable automatic creation of namespaces for Application objects in Argo CD?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I want to disable automatic creation of namespaces for Application objects in Argo CD, since Argo CD users shouldn't be allowed to create new namespaces, but only use existing namespaces.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

normally there is a `syncPolicy` like the below:

```
  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```

you will want to remove the option `CreateNamespace=true` from the application manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the argocd install manifests, it looks like the only ClusterRole which has permissions to create namespaces is:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: application-controller
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-application-controller
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-application-controller
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- nonResourceURLs:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

I have not tested this out, but I would guess that limiting this so the argocd service account cannot create new namespaces would fix the issue. Hope this helps.

I am curious about implementing the same thing in a nicer way.